# Induction (Geometric sequence)

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, geometric-series

There are two one-letter words in English (“I” and “a”), and according to http://www.scrabble.org.au/words/twos.htm there are 122 two-letter words. Let $A_n$ be the number of strings of n letters that may be formed from some sequence of one- and two-letter words, by concatenating them all together.

Find $a_3$

Give an expression for an in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$, that works for all n ≥ 3.

So far a1 makes sense to just be "I" and "a" so a total of 2.
a2 would be the 122 two letter strings plus a combination of adding the one letter words (i and a) giving ai, ia, ii and aa.

This would give a total of 126 for $a_2$.

doing the combinations for $a_3$ gives 495 but that doesn't seem right as there is no evident patter to use the formula $a_n=a_1r^{n-1}$.

Comment: The answer (probably) won't be a purely geometric sequence, but rather a sum of two, so something like $b_1r_1^n + b_2r_2^n$ for some constants $b_i, r_i$

Comment: How to you get to 495 for $a_3$? And why do you think it should be a geometric sequence? When you have a string of $n$ letters and the first one is a one-letter word what is left? What is left if the first two letters form a two letter word?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer the following (perhaps slightly simplified) question:

**Problem:**  Suppose that there are exactly two distinct strings of length 1 (say $a_1$ and $a_2$), and 122 distinct strings of length 2 (say $b_1,b_2,\dotsc,b_{122}$---note that I am assuming $a_ia_j \ne b_k$ for any $i,j,k$; that is, none of the original strings of length 2 is formed by concatenating strings of length 1).  Let $A_n$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ that can be formed by concatenating the 124 distinct strings described above.  What is $A_n$ for each $n$?

*Solution:*  First, note that $A_1 = 2$ (as there are exactly two strings of length 1), and $A_2 = 126$ (there are 122 distinct strings of length 2, plus four strings of length 2 that are obtained by concatenating strings of length 1).

To determine $A_n$, note that there are two ways in which we can form a string of length $n$:

1. We can append a string of length 1 to a string of length $n-1$.  There are 2 strings of length 1, and $A_{n-1}$ strings of length $n-1$, and we are free to choose each, hence there are $2A_{n-1}$ ways of forming a string of length $n$ in this manner.
2. We can append a string of length 2 to a string of length $n-2$.  There are 126 strings of length 2 and $A_{n-2}$ strings of length $n-2$, and we are again free to choose each, hence there are $126A_{n-2}$ ways of forming a string of length $n$ in this manner.

Combining these, we obtain
$$ A_n = 2 A_{n-1} + 126 A_{n-2},$$
which gives a formula for computing $A_n$ for any $n$.

If you require a closed form in terms of $n$, the general idea is that $A_n$ is given by
$$ A_n = C_1 r_1^n + C_2 r_2^n, $$
where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants, and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are zeros of the characteristic polynomial (assuming that all of the zeros have multiplicity 1; this gets slightly more complicated if we allow higher order zeros).  In this problem, the characteristic polynomial is given by
$$ p(t) = t^2 - 2t + 126. $$
Setting this equal to zero and solving for $t$ gives us
\begin{align}
0 = t^2 - 2t + 126 = (t-1)^2 + 125
&\implies (t-1)^2 = 125 \\
&\implies t-1 = \pm\sqrt{125} = \pm 5\sqrt{5} \\
&\implies t = 1 \pm 5\sqrt{5}.
\end{align}
Thus the closed from looks like
$$ A_n = C_1 (1+5\sqrt{5})^n + C_2(1-5\sqrt{5})^n. $$
Since $A_1 = 2$ and $A_2 = 126$, we can determine $C_1$ and $C_2$ by solving the system
$$
\begin{cases}
2 = C_1 (1+5\sqrt{5}) + C_2(1-5\sqrt{5}) \\
126 = C_1 (1+5\sqrt{5})^2 + C_2(1-5\sqrt{5})^2.
\end{cases}
$$
This should doable by hand, but I am quite lazy---Maple suggests that the correct solution is
$$ C_1 = \frac{61}{124} + \frac{63}{3100}\sqrt{5},
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
C_2 = \frac{61}{124} - \frac{63}{3100}\sqrt{5}.
$$
Therefore
$$
 A_n = \left( \frac{61}{124} + \frac{63}{3100}\sqrt{5} \right)\left( 1+5\sqrt{5} \right)^n + \left( \frac{61}{124} - \frac{63}{3100}\sqrt{5} \right)\left( 1-5\sqrt{5} \right)^n,
$$
which gives a closed form formula for $A_n$ in all of its tedious glory.