# Mathematical Induction question talking about words

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is the question:
[image: the question]

I am still struggling with this and here is my answer so far:

[image: my answer so far]

I found some difficulties to get the a3. Can you check my implementation? then, how do I actually get the expression for my finding?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to math.SE. On this site we use [MathJax to typeset mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It makes all the math on the site appear uniform, readable and (somewhat) searchable. Please consider typing up your screenshots, and especially your answer so far, in order to make it more available to people reading your question (especially on phone). Also, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393111/induction-geometric-sequence), which is highly related.