# Solving Problem by Induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I've been stuck on the following puzzle:

> There are $2$ one-letter words in English ("I" and "a"), and there are $124$ two-letter words.
>
> Let $a_n$ be the number of strings of $n$ letter that may be formed from some sequence of one- and two-letter words, by concatenating them all together.
>
> Prove, by induction on $n$, that $a_n \le 13^n \ \forall n$.

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I read over that question, but it doesn't seem to address the induction at all.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395223/306553  Do you have an expression linking $a_{n}$, $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ ? Would you like to include it in your post?

Comment: You might want to have a proof by induction that estimates, rather than finds exactly (as the proposed duplicate Question finds), the value $a_n$.  However in its present form your Question lacks much context (you've "been stuck" and "would appreciate" a solution).  Please add details of where you got stuck or why you find this problem interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. A string of lenght $n+1$ may end with a one letter word of with a two-letter word. Therefore for $n\geq 2$,
$$a_{n+1}\leq 2a_n+124a_{n-1}.$$
Now show the inequality by induction. In the inductive step note that
$$a_{n+1}\leq 2a_n+124a_{n-1}\leq 2\cdot 13^n+124\cdot 13^{n-1}=
(2\cdot 13+124)13^{n-1}\leq 13^{n+1}.$$

Comment: For that, you would first have to show that none of the two-letter words ends in i or a, otherwise there might be a word with $n+1$ letters that falls in both categories. You get, however, a $\leq$ here, and that should suffice for the desired result.

Comment: @Dirk Libehold. Good point. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Robert, how would one show the inequality by induction? This is the part I am having trouble with.

Comment: @handler's handle See my edited answer.

Comment: @RobertZ I understand now. Thanks, Robert!

Comment: @RobertZ The last less-or-equal is actually strictly less: $2\cdot 13+124 = 150 < 169 = 13^2$.